# how to trigger Jenkins build job from XL Release Task

Tags: jenkins, xlrelease

We have been using '[XL Release](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-release/)' server (XLR) for projects' release management and Jenkins for continuous Integration of projects from GitHub. I am trying to create a Jenkins task for one Release on XLR by providing the basic configuration like Jenkins URL/user name/password and the Jenkins job name which are mandatory.

Now when I am starting the Task in XLR, it gives the following Error message as below:

"Failed to connect at http://[Jenkins server]/job//build. Status: 405"

### Along with the response looks like the below script:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&lt;html&gt;&lt;head resURL="/static/84561821"&gt;


&lt;title&gt;Form post required [Jenkins]&lt;/title&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/css/style.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/css/color.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/css/responsive-grid.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/static/84561821/favicon.ico" /&gt;&lt;script&gt;var isRunAsTest=false; var rootURL=""; var resURL="/static/84561821";&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/behavior.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src='/adjuncts/84561821/org/kohsuke/stapler/bind.js' type='text/javascript'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/dom/dom-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/event/event-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/animation/animation-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/container/container-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/connection/connection-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/datasource/datasource-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/menu/menu-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/element/element-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/button/button-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/storage/storage-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/hudson-behavior.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/sortable.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script&gt;crumb.init("", "");&lt;/script&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/container/assets/container.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/assets/skins/sam/skin.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/container/assets/skins/sam/container.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css" /&gt;&lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css" /&gt;&lt;link title="Jenkins" rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml" /&gt;&lt;meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,NOFOLLOW" /&gt;&lt;script src="/static/84561821/scripts/yui/cookie/cookie-min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body id="jenkins" data-version="jenkins-1.612" class="yui-skin-sam jenkins-1.612"&gt;&lt;a href="#skip2content" class="skiplink"&gt;Skip to content&lt;/a&gt;&lt;div id="page-head"&gt;&lt;div id="header"&gt;&lt;div class="logo"&gt;&lt;a id="jenkins-home-link" href="/"&gt;&lt;img id="jenkins-head-icon" alt="title" src="/static/84561821/images/headshot.png" /&gt;&lt;img id="jenkins-name-icon" height="34" alt="title" width="139" src="/static/84561821/images/title.png" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="login"&gt; &lt;span style="white-space:nowrap"&gt;&lt;a class="model-link inside inverse" href="/user/admin"&gt;&lt;b&gt;Admin&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                |
                &lt;a href="/logout"&gt;&lt;b&gt;log out&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="searchbox hidden-xs"&gt;&lt;form style="position:relative;" name="search" action="/job/XLRConnect/search/" class="no-json" method="get"&gt;&lt;div id="search-box-minWidth"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="search-box-sizer"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="searchform"&gt;&lt;input id="search-box" placeholder="search" name="q" class="has-default-text" /&gt; &lt;a href="http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Search+Box"&gt;&lt;img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; " class="icon-help icon-sm" src="/static/84561821/images/16x16/help.png" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;div id="search-box-completion"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;script&gt;createSearchBox("/job/XLRConnect/search/");&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/form&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="breadcrumbBar"&gt;&lt;tr id="top-nav"&gt;&lt;td id="left-top-nav" colspan="2"&gt;&lt;link rel='stylesheet' href='/adjuncts/84561821/lib/layout/breadcrumbs.css' type='text/css' /&gt;&lt;script src='/adjuncts/84561821/lib/layout/breadcrumbs.js' type='text/javascript'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;div class="top-sticker noedge"&gt;&lt;div class="top-sticker-inner"&gt;&lt;div id="right-top-nav"&gt;&lt;div id="right-top-nav"&gt;&lt;div class="smallfont"&gt;&lt;a href="?auto_refresh=true"&gt;ENABLE AUTO REFRESH&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;ul id="breadcrumbs"&gt;&lt;li class="item"&gt;&lt;a class="model-link inside" href="/"&gt;Jenkins&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class="children" href="/"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class="item"&gt;&lt;a class="model-link inside" href="/job/XLRConnect/"&gt;XLRConnect&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class="children" href="/job/XLRConnect/"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;div id="breadcrumb-menu-target"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="page-body"&gt;&lt;div class="row"&gt;&lt;div id="side-panel"&gt;&lt;div id="side-panel-content"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="main-panel"&gt;&lt;div id="main-panel-content"&gt;&lt;a name="skip2content"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;p&gt;You must use POST method to trigger builds. (From scripts you may instead pass a per-project authentication token, or authenticate with your API token.) If you see this page, it may be because a plugin offered a GET link; file a bug report for that plugin.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;form method="POST"&gt;&lt;input value="Proceed" type="submit" /&gt;&lt;/form&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="footer-container" class="hidden-xs"&gt;&lt;div id="footer"&gt;&lt;span class="page_generated"&gt;
      Page generated:
      May 15, 2015 7:19:33 AM&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="rest_api"&gt;&lt;a href="api/"&gt;REST API&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class="jenkins_ver"&gt;&lt;a href="http://jenkins-ci.org/"&gt;Jenkins ver. 1.612&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div id="l10n-dialog" class="dialog"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id="l10n-footer" style="display:none; float:left"&gt;&lt;a href="#" onclick="return showTranslationDialog();"&gt;&lt;img src="/static/84561821/plugin/translation/flags.png" /&gt;
  Help us localize this page
&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;script&gt;var footer = document.getElementById('l10n-footer');
var f = document.getElementById('footer');
f.insertBefore(footer,f.firstChild);
footer.style.display="block";

var translation={}; 
translation.bundles = "2/IQrALgQj5lxSaSGgxqQQkSUo1ENoPujAvbNoPJBK21a2oKoF/JGOpvDglu0VebF5yobsoJyFLor25mINHZlxHylXblrqHOuffnUiU91xUSw1gbTHkbtyOsTKsLGVLKw+X2jk0M8bGwrntRODX2cfYB5AJ8mQaEVEmEwEZD1sCFMVG2gQHzDmgiIVBSBPtqCOjg5K4JvO0BpT9HTnxudGzYRNvIi+Dln94MShP6x3g3gP83NCpANQ7L+7XkvT3Q5cifZcX37D4vYCyYpERPJc9hO5WlbsUd7DJEAvVwemi7azuvAfJEQ34mjOBf2+72xE/EYKxZv85GUpwC79oVObY0jBPF+WHG94syh70ZYIw=";
translation.detectedLocale = "";

function showTranslationDialog() {
  if(!translation.launchDialog)
    loadScript("/static/84561821/plugin/translation/dialog.js");
  else
    translation.launchDialog();
  return false; 
}&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

### And the response header looks like

```
Response headers: {'X-Frame-Options': 'sameorigin', 'X-Instance-Identity': 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyIYGgQSshNjxYz1dxA4h4OQtyFz00oXjDDjMSeJmR0o9Qrr9CkDYnrjuher6aMj/ls8qI2um+CHk9zVwUeSTzHhBIg29V+l7Hu4k9RF18ZY2omMDgonvuH9sqBpKAu4/S1U+RXQuQIKQk/66+UhhXPL3EYqYiNPuvRHXfhqIjXqH8Ts58q1ueuJ06b63RcnAx1z3XEq/pBMImz1HaXFhqS//FVhnx6Rl+AC7pXksR+vchyk8M9oHixtHk4lqaJxCgdAjydojVagPwEeh98TfBcmhjdLQhdLNaTe0SB7agNgiN0rgwzC9CCbQYlFMcYZ2UrcsPL5XsFRs8sqiMlPpswIDAQAB', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Jenkins-CLI-Port': '41603', 'X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port': '41603', 'X-Jenkins-Session': '84561821', 'X-Hudson-CLI-Port': '41603', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate', 'Allow': 'POST', 'X-Hudson': '1.395', 'Server': 'Jetty(winstone-2.8)', 'X-Jenkins': '1.612', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID.fa5428c3=158cuy2kt13l64ci0bpcstd9b;Path=/;HttpOnly', 'X-Hudson-Theme': 'default', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', 'X-SSH-Endpoint': '10.80.250.149:48964'}

Exception during execution: SystemExit: 1 in <script> at line number 113
```

### Question

Is there any prerequisite for this kind of setup? Or Am I missing anything from Jenkins configuration?

It will be very helpful if somebody can point out to any direction. Till now I am unable to find any proper documentation for this combination (Jenkins+XLR) though both the tools support each other by default.

Note: There is one XL Release plug-in for Jenkins which helps to create a new release through a build job. But my requirement is quite reverse where a task from XLR will trigger Jenkins build job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Jenkins with security enabled? If so, the following article *"Configure the XL Release Jenkins plugin to invoke secured Jenkins installations"* might help:

https://support.xebialabs.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202581015-How-To-Configure-the-XL-Release-Jenkins-plugin-to-invoke-secured-Jenkins-installations-by-sending-POSTs

Regards

ap